# Get the subfolder from current url

Tags: joomla-3.9

I'am wondering how to get into Joomla! component the subfolder from the current URL.

Is-there a way to achieve this ?

Thnaks by advance

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the term "subfolder"? It may be that you want one of  the path constants which are listed here https://docs.joomla.org/Constants

Comment: By subfolder, i mean when joomla! is installed in subfolder and so this subfolder appears in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri::root(true)`. Note it returns the path with leading slash. E.g. if site address is `https://example.com/joomla/testing/`, this returns `/joomla/testing`.